# Need setParameterList alternative

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been using this method from hibernate SQLQuery:

```
setParameter(int position, Object val)
```

for some time. Now I wanna use array parameters, but there is no function

```
setParameterList(int position, Object val)
```

only:

```
setParameterList(String name, Object val)
```

There's a big problem for me, because I wanna use '?' to set location of parameters in my queries instead of giving full names (':someparameter'). Is there any possible way to solve my problem?

Comment: Afaik JDBC doesn't allow parameter lists so Hibernate would translate `:list` to something like `?,?,...?`. Because of that using positional parameters for lists might not be possible. I'd suggest using named parameters anyway because those are less likely to break if you need to move things around or add/remove a parameter somewhere but the end.

Comment: if you really want to use `?`, you could just build the query with a `for` and add as many positional parameters as you need for your list, and the you set all of them one by one, but it doesn't sound like a good idea to me.